# Wget - download website from second depth

Tags: linux, command, wget

Can I download website with wget from second depth and next sublevels?
I want to download only pages which refer from the first level, but not download the first level.

For example:

- I have a domain with structure: www.domain.cz/foo/bar/baz
- I want to download only pages: bar and bar/baz

It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-np`.

> -np
>   --no-parent
>
> Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving
>   recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only
>   the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.

Comment: Ok, but it will download all first level. I do not want entry: wget  --no-parent www.domain.cz/foo/bar, because I do not know uri foo or bar, but i want entry something like this: wget www.domain.cz -r --start-depth=2. Do you understand me?

Comment: @user3468684 Yes I understand you :)

Comment: No I don't think wget has that kind of feature.

Answer (score 1):

You may download the index file on the top level, then feed it with -`i index.html` and optionally set `--base=http://www.domain.cz` and directory options like `--force-directories`. Depending on the content there, you might want to reduce the index file contents (extract only wanted subdirs).